# Старт ввода в input при открытии модального окна

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap4

На сайте есть кнопка, при нажатии на нее открывается модальное окно. В модальном окне есть input. Как сделать так, чтобы при открытии модального окна сразу можно было печатать в input, без отдельного нажатия на него?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var input = document.querySelector('input');

button.addEventListener('click', openModal);

function openModal() {
 // your code...
  input.focus();
}
```

```html
<button>кнопка открытия модального окна</button>
<input type="text">
```

В твоем случае, нужно подождать пока у модального окна появится класс `shown`. Сколько точно по времени, ты наверное лучше знаешь, потому что я не использую эти библиотеки.

```
var button = document.querySelector('#search');
var input = document.querySelector('#story');

button.addEventListener('click', openModal);
function openModal() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    input.focus();
  }, 500)
}
```

Или вот вариант на jquery(взято отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/a/11634933/12226424):

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#story').focus();
})
```

Comment: Спасибо, вижу что то, что нужно, но объясните, пожалуйста, почему не работает здесь? https://jsfiddle.net/fzwsjnc8/3/

Comment: Спасибо огромное, вариант на jQuery отличный!